# How change 'InnertText' into span without ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, innerhtml, innertext

How i can modify the InnerText or InnerHTML of span ***without* id**:

```
<span class="..."...>
```

with JQuery or JavaScript?

The complete code:

```
<span class="o365cs-nav-brandingText">Correo de Outlook</span>
```

I want modify the *"Correo de Outlook"* with a code.

[my HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhAw5.jpg)

Comment: If you have the class name (or ID) of your ancestors in your html markup you can use selectors to refer to that span.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.querySelector('span').innerText = 'new text I want';

document.querySelector('span').innerHTML = '<b>new text I want</b>';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the class name you could use:

```
$(".o365cs-nav-brandingText").html("...");
```

If you only have a single span, you could use:

```
$("span").html("...");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select element from `class` name.

**Core JS**

```js
document.querySelector('.o365cs-nav-brandingText').textContent = "New text";
```

```html
<span class="o365cs-nav-brandingText">Correo de Outlook</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what do you know about element you want to select.

• If the class name is known:

```
<span class="o365cs-nav-brandingText">Correo de Outlook</span>

$(".o365cs-nav-brandingText").text("New text");
```

• If specific attribute is known:

```
<span myAttr="attrValue">Correo de Outlook</span>

$("[myAttr='attrValue']").text("New text");
```

• If you know just tag name (keep in mind that it will select all elements with same tag name):

```
<span>Correo de Outlook</span>

$("span").text("New text");
```

• You can also use some parent elements to make your selection more accurate:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <span>Correo de Outlook</span>
</div>

$(".wrapper span").text("New text");
```

Learn more about selecting elements with jQuery [here](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/) or [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp).

Answer (score 0):

If you know the class name, use below lines of code：

```
$(".o365cs-nav-brandingText").text("Text");
```